# Wordpress WPML String Translation

Tags: php, wordpress, translate, po, wpml

I have a problem with my theme translation because it is not a string but span and I can't translate.

I use **WPML String Translation** Widget.

This is the source code in **SinlePost.php**

```
<?php
                $prev_post = get_previous_post();
                $next_post = get_next_post();

                if ( !empty( $prev_post ) ){ 
                ?>
                <div class="nav-previous">
                    <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i><span class="sub-title">Previous article</span><br />%title' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

and how should I modify to translate words ***Previous Post*** into my native language.

Please help me, because I am a beginner in Wordpress?
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happen if you use the function `__(` inside the function `previous_post_link`?

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', __('<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i><span class="sub-title">Previous article</span><br />%title') ); ?>
```

After you need to rescan your theme in your wp-admin and then go in String Tranlation page to see if it's there.

Maybe it's not the solution but try it and tell me what it gives you.

Comment: this string generated:


`<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i><span class="sub-title">Previous article</span><br />%title`

Comment: Super ! Pleasure to help you !